# Vue component functionality suddenly doesn't working without modifying the code

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, express, vue-component, single-page-application

On my Vue.js SPA project i have an instagram-like image board. It's a full-stack project with express.js postgresSQL on the backend. whenever user clicks an image a modal is opening showing the image and comments of other users to that image. Users can navigate to the next/previous image with next/previous buttons within the modal and accordingly the comments to the new image will appear.

The modal is a component inside the main app.js. file. Inside the modal component there's a second component for the users comments.

Everything worked perfect like it should be, as described above. Suddenly, without touching or modifying any of the code, something broke: now, when user navigates between images with next/previous buttons, the new image appears but the comments of the old image stay the same without showing the comments which are relevant to the new image.

- If instead of navigating with the next/previous buttons i would close the modal and just click another image, i would get the relevant comments for that image.

I reviewed and checked my code for too long now and can not figure out what went wrong, even more strange that it worked and out of nowhere stopped working. Does anyone had a similar case or has an idea what could lead to that? Can it be server related issue?

app.js

```
import * as Vue from "./vue.js";
import modalComponent from "./modal-component.js";

Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            name: "images",
            images: [],
            imgClicked: "",
            imagePath: "",
            moreButton: true,
            imageSelected: false,
            userInput: { username: "", description: "", title: "" },
            formNotValid: false,
            errorMsg: false,
            isMobile: false,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(window.innerWidth);
        history.pushState({}, "", "/home");
        this.imagePath = "";
        this.imageRemoved = false;
        this.errorMsg = false;

        fetch("/image_board")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.images = data;
                console.log("fetched-data: ", data);
            });

        window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
            let path = location.pathname.slice(1);
            if (path != "") {
                path = Number.parseInt(path);
                if (Number.isNaN(path)) {
                    history.replaceState({}, "", "/");
                } else {
                    this.idCard = path;
                }
            } else {
                this.imgClicked = "";
            }
        });
    },
    components: {
        "modal-component": modalComponent,
    },
    methods: {
   ......

        updateImg(newRenderedImgId) {
            this.imgClicked = newRenderedImgId;
            history.pushState({}, "", `/${this.imgClicked}`);
        },
    },
}).mount("#app_container");
```

/****************************************************/

index.html

` 
<modal-component v-if="imgClicked" v-bind:selected-Img="imgClicked" @update="updateImg" @close="closeModalComponent">

`

/****************************************************/

modal-component.js

```
import commentsComponent from "./comments-component.js";

const modalComponent = {
    data() {
        return {
            header: "modal-component",
            img: {},
            rendernNextBtn: true,
            renderPreviousBtn: true,
            nextImgOnScreen: null,
            previousImgOnScreen: null,
        };
    },
    props: ["selectedImg"],
    components: {
        "comments-component": commentsComponent,
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    watch: {
        selectedImg: function () {
            this.fetchData();
            this.img.id = this.img.nextId || this.img.previousId;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            console.log("this.selectedImg: ", this.selectedImg);
            this.rendernNextBtn = true;
            this.renderPreviousBtn = true;

            fetch(`/image_board/${this.selectedImg}`)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    this.img = data;
                    if (this.img.previousId === null) {
                        this.renderPreviousBtn = false;
                    }
                    if (this.img.nextId === null) {
                        this.rendernNextBtn = false;
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("error: problem fetching data: ", err);
                });
        },
        close() {
            this.$emit("close");
        },
        nextImgId() {
            console.log(this.img.nextId);
            this.$emit("update", this.img.nextId);
        },
        previousImgId() {
            console.log(this.img.previousId);
            this.$emit("update", this.img.previousId);
        },
    },
    template: `
    <div class="modal_wrapper_div">
        <div class="modal_component_div">
            <div class="span_x_div">
                <span @click="close" class=close-tag>x</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal_img_div">
                <div class="next_previous_img_div">
                    <div v-if="renderPreviousBtn" @click="previousImgId" class="previous_div">
                        <span>«</span>
                    </div>
                    <div v-if="rendernNextBtn" @click="nextImgId" class="next_div">
                        <span>»</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img v-bind:src="img.url" v-bind:alt="img.title" v-bind:key="img.id"/><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="user_details_div">
                <div class="user_details_container">
                    <div class="img_title_wrapper">
                        <h3>{{img.title}}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user_details_par_container">
                        <p class="uploaded_by_par">Uploaded By:<br>{{img.username}}, {{img.created_at}}</p><br>
                        <p class="decription_par">Description:<br>{{img.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <comments-component v-bind:img-id="selectedImg"></comments-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
};

export default modalComponent;
```

/****************************************************/

comments-component.js

```
const commentsComponent = {
    data() {
        return {
            comments: [],
            username: "",
            comment: "",
        };
    },
    props: ["imgId"],
    mounted() {
        fetch(`/comments/${this.imgId}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((fetchedData) => {
                console.log(
                    "FETCHED DATA: comments are retreived",
                    fetchedData
                );
                this.comments = fetchedData;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("ERROR: PROBLEM TO FETCH DATA ", err);
            });
    },
    methods: {
        handleCommentSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            fetch("/comment", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    comment: this.comment,
                    username: this.username,
                    image_id: this.imgId,
                }),
            })
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    this.comments.unshift(data.payload);
                    this.username = "";
                    this.comment = "";
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    "Error fetch comments: ", err;
                });
        },
    },
    template: `
    <div class="comments_component_div">    
        <div class="comments_form_div">
            <form class="comments_form">
                <input class="username_input" v-model='username' type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name">
                <textarea class="comment_input" v-model='comment' id="commentbox" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Add Your Comment..." cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <button class="comments_button" @click="handleCommentSubmit">Add Comment</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="single_comment_box" v-if="comments.length" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">
            <div class="list_item">
                <p id="username_par">{{comment.username}}:</p>
                <p id="comment_par">{{comment.comment}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
};

export default commentsComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your CommentsComponent loads comments only once when it is mounted. If `imgId` changes, you need to load the comments again. You could just replace the mounted with an eager watcher on that property:

```
watch:{
  imgId:{
    immediate: true,
    async handler(){   
      this.comments = await fetch(`/comments/${this.imgId}`).then(res => res.json())
    }
  },
```

Can't tell you why it worked before though.